# Check if ip belongs to subnet in python3

Tags: python-3.x, ip, subnet

I'm trying to check if a list of ip addresses (list called ips) belong to a list of subnets (list called subnets). If one ip from ips belong to subnet from subnets, it is considered as scanned. My goal is to find not scanned subnets.
I wrote this small script which seems to work, but the actual result is not accurate. What do I mean by saying that: it is accurately parses the subnets from a file (there are 100 subnets), but after the for executing it appears to miss some results, because in the end there are only 97 subnets. Any help will be appreciated.

Data looks like this:

```
ip adresses:
172.0.0.1
172.0.0.2
etc

subnets:
172.0.0.1/24
186.0.0.1/30
etc
```

the code fragment:

```
print(len(subnets)) #returns 100
for ip in ips:
        for subnet in subnets:
                if(ip in subnet):
                        scanned.append(subnet) 

scanned = list(set(scanned))
notscanned = [x for x in subnets if x not in scanned]
print(len(scanned + notscanned)) #returns 97
```

Comment: Please provide a copy-pasteable sample of your data

Comment: @JanWilamowski Hi, Jan

Comment: do you have duplicate entries in your subnets?

Comment: Well, no. but thanks for an idea, I forgot there may be a case, some networks may be included in another ones. Thank you!